# How to calculate sum of a DataTable's Column in LINQ (to Dataset)?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, sum

I'm just started to read up on LINQ and I want to start incorporating it into my code. I know how to compute the sum of a DataTable's column by either "Foreach"-ing through the rows or by doing a compute.sum on the specific column. How do I do the equivalent with LINQ to DataSet?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

If untyped (replace `int` with the correct data type):

```
 var sum = table.AsEnumerable().Sum(x=>x.Field<int>(3));
```

or:

```
 var sum = table.AsEnumerable().Sum(x=>x.Field<int>("SomeProperty"));
```

If typed:

```
 var sum = table.Sum(x=>x.SomeProperty);
```

Comment: Note that you need the System.Data.DataSetExtensions Assembly for the above to work.

Comment: @kervin: also, you need to make sure this is on top of your code file: `using System.Linq;`

Comment: just to understand and if i am correct, when you say `typed` and `un-typed` does it mean typed view and un-typed view in [asp mvc](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/04/13/asp-net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models) , i mean the ViewModel class that we create ?

Answer (score 2):

**If you data field is integer**

```
var sum = TableData.Sum(x => x.FieldName);
```

**If your data field is string then you need to parse it as integer**

```
var sum = TableData.Sum(x => Int32.Parse(x.FieldName));
```

**If your data field is string and you want to store result as string**

```
var sum = TableData.Sum(x => Int32.Parse(x.FieldName)).ToString();
```