# computing sum of numeric column in c# .net

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate sum of a DataTable's Column in LINQ (to Dataset)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550187/how-to-calculate-sum-of-a-datatables-column-in-linq-to-dataset)

In my Data_Grid_View, I have one numeric column named Amount and I want to display total of this column in one text box ,can anyone tell what will be the code for it in c# .net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you would do it with LINQ, assuming your amounts were `double`:

```
dataGridView.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Sum(row => Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Amount"].Value));
```

Here's how it would actually fit into your program:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal sum = dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                  .Sum(row => Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["Money"].Value));
    textBox1.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

Comment: How do you get the Sum? When I type dataGridView.Rows. I cannot find "Sum" Anywhere and I tried searching the documentation. Also I'm already using System.Linq

Comment: MrFox: Thanks for catching that. It needs `OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
` because `Rows` implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<T>` (which is required by LINQ).

Comment: private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Sum(row => Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Money"].Value));
            textBox1.Text = sum.ToString();

        }                                                       this is showing me 0 answer in text_box field ,wat should i do?

Comment: @cat20: It's showing you 0 because you never put anything besides 0 into `sum`. See my edit for how to do it properly.

Comment: Hey thank you so much it's working ,can you tell me if i directly want to show the sum in text box without having button then how should i do?

Comment: Hey Thank you so much it's working ,can you tell me that if i want to show the sum directly in text box without having button than how can i do?

Comment: @cat20: That's an entirely different question. You'll have to ask that separately.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 int sum = 0;
 int ColumnIndex=1; //your column index 

 //Iterate through all the cells of Specified ColumnIndex in each row and get the sum 
 for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
 {
    sum += int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
 }
 //display sum 
 textBox1.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Comment: `textBox1.Text = sum.ToString()`!

Comment: I have added your code on TextBox click private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            int ColumnIndex = 2; //your column index 

            //Iterate through all the cells of Specified ColumnIndex in each row and get the sum 
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
            {
                sum += int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
            }
            //display sum 
            textBox1.Text = sum.ToString();

        }

Comment: Are you facing any problem with this...??

Comment: I have added your code by clicking on text_box ,it is not showing me error but not also showing me sum in text_box,i should write this code on text_box click only right?

Comment: You may want to write this code in some button_click event in order to test it ...!!

Comment: when i write it inbutton_click event it is throwing this Exception-These methods throw a FormatException if the supplied argument is not in a format that can be converted. Double.Parse will throw a FormatException if its string argument is not in a recognizable numeric format.