# gridview selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've one grid view named gvSector.
The fields of this table is as follows:

```
Sector Name    Amount Invested
Finance        300000
Properties     100000
...            ...
```

Condition: If the amount invested in a particular sector is more than 30%
My label `lbSector` will show the sector name.

My code in the .cs file is as follows.

```
double TotalInvestments = 0.0;

for (int i = 0; i < gvSector.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (gvSector.Rows.Count > 0)
    {   
        double SAmt = Convert.ToDouble(gvSector.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text);
        TotalInvestments += SAmt;
        double PercentSAmt = (SAmt / TotalInvestments) * 100;

        if (PercentSAmt > 25.0)
        {
            //I've no idea what to put here. It is supposed to show the sector(s) that is more than 25% from the gridview.

        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: You should do the calculation in the dbms(f.e. as SP `getTopSectors` which takes an % value as argument).

Comment: Yes you can, but you should not need to do it normally. It's also unclear what you're trying to achieve. Do all records have to be shown or only that with sector >= 30%?

Comment: the data in database is all historical data. Like buying and selling of stocks. It shouldn't store the percentage of holdings in dbms right?

Comment: The name of the sector with sector>30% will be shown as lbSector (An label).

Answer (score 0):

1) Doing the following in the for loop wonT give you what you need.

```
        double SAmt = Convert.ToDouble(gvSector.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text);
        TotalInvestments += SAmt;
        double PercentSAmt = (SAmt / TotalInvestments) * 100;
```

Instead calculate the `TotalInvestments` elsewhere beforehand.

- using linq: [How to calculate sum of a DataTable's Column in LINQ (to Dataset)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550187/how-to-calculate-sum-of-a-datatables-column-in-linq-to-dataset)
- wihtout linq using `DataTable.Compute` : [msdn post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharplanguage/thread/b5184aca-6264-4079-8434-7a0cf43baf2c)

2) If you want to show the rows conditionally,  you can change the visibility of your `GridViewRow` or remove the row from `DataTable` before binding and so on.

```
 double PercentSAmt = (SAmt / TotalInvestments) * 100;
 if (PercentSAmt > 30.0)
 {           
    gvSector.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text
 }
```

**Edit**: if you want to list the sectors in your label ( though i donT know how you are going to structure the text)

```
double PercentSAmt = (SAmt / TotalInvestments) * 100;
 if (PercentSAmt > 30.0)
 {           
    lbSector.Text +=  gvSector.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text + " ";
 }
```

Comment: lbsector is the name of my label

Comment: Where is your `lbSector` ( is it a column data `ItemTemplate` in the `GridView` ? or is it just a label outside of the grid ? )

Comment: it's a label outside the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Normally i would do such calculations in the DBMS(f.e. in a Stored-Procedure or table-valued-function). This is faster and better reusable than hardlinking it with a GridView of an ASP.NET application.

I'm not sure if you only want tro show the Top-Sectors in GridView or all but the Label should only display the name if it belongs to the top-sectors.

If the latter, you should do that in [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) of the GridView. On this way you only have only one loop and only on databinding:

```
protected void Grid_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        var data = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
        var lbSector = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbSector");
        var amount = (int)data("Amount");
        var amountOverAll = (long)data.DataView.Table.Compute("SUM(Amount)", null);
        if (amount * 100 / amountOverAll >= 30) {
            lbSector.Text = data("Sector").ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

You can use [DataTable.Compute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx) to calculate this value as shown above.