# How to find matching records in data table

Tags: c#, datatable, sum

I've got a data table with with two collumns: a number and a date, for **example :**

> 125 | 2013/10/20
>   100 | 2013/10/21
>   150 | 2013/10/24
>   225 | 2013/10/24
>   250 | 2013/10/28
>   310 | 2013/10/30

now, I want to search for all records ordered by date where the sum of the number matches 500. I can easily see that the **first, third and fourth record (125 + 150 + 225 = 500) provide a match**, but to program such, I can only think of going through the data table a zillion of times until I found the right match.

Has anybody a smarter idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate sum of a DataTable's Column in LINQ (to Dataset)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550187/how-to-calculate-sum-of-a-datatables-column-in-linq-to-dataset)

Comment: How many records do you have?

Comment: @Liam - no, not really unfortunately

Comment: @bump - it could be over a thousand

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum)

Comment: As far as I understand your (125 + 150 + 225 = 500) example, there's no date ordering involved. Actually, I'm pretty sure a performant solution would involve ordering the rows by number.

Comment: Do you mean where the sum of the number BY DATE = 500?  If so you want a group by statement, your question doesn't seem to indicate any grouping however.

Comment: This is the [Subset Sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problem.

Comment: Are you trying to find the solution that has the earliest set of dates or all solutions?

Comment: It depends on the constraints you have on `Number`.  If you assume that `Number` is non-negative, you can put a stopping condition into your recursive search that will give you decent performance.  If you have an upper bound (or a positive lower bound) on `Number` then life gets even better because you can tighten up the stopping condition and achieve better performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the worst case, you do have to go through all `2^n` subsets of your dataset, but if all of your items are non-negative you can start by filtering on `item.Number <= 500`.

Here is a possible `Subsets` method (actually an answer to [How to get all subsets of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999050/most-elegant-way-to-get-all-subsets-of-an-array-in-c-sharp), but don't tell them):

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Subsets(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var first = source.FirstOrDefault();
    if (first == null) return new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };

    var others = source.Skip(1).Subsets();
    return others.Concat(others.Select(s => s.Concat(new { first })));
}
```

Once you have your `Subsets` method, then you can filter the result as follows, though performance is still of the order of a gazillion (or `2^n` if you want to be picky).

```
var sets = items.Where(i => i.Number <= 500)
    .Subsets().Where(s => s.Sum(i => i.Number) == 500);
```

However, if you do have the constraint on `Number`, that it is non-negative, you can combine the `Subsets` operation with a search for a target sum.  That would mean you would define

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SubsetsAddingUpTo(this IEnumerable<T> source, int target)
{
    // This stopping condition ensures that you will not have to walk the rest of the tree when you have already hit or exceeded your target.
    // It assumes that the Number values are all non-negative.
    if (target < 0) return Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<T>>();

    var first = source.FirstOrDefault();
    if (first == null) return Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<T>>();

    var tail = source.Skip(1).Where(i => i.Number <= target).ToList();

    var othersIncludingFirst = tail.SubsetsAddingUpTo(target - first.Number);
    var othersExcludingFirst = tail.SubsetsAddingUpTo(target);

    return othersExcludingFirst.Concat(othersIncludingFirst.Select(s => s.Concat(new { first })));
}
```

Because the check for `<= target` happens inside the method, you don't have to do any pre-filtering.  However, you can perform a sort before you do the search, to give you your sets in a hierarchical date order.  The call will be

```
var sets = items.OrderByDescending(i => i.Date).SubsetsAddingUpTo(500);
```

This should actually give you decent performance.  The worst case (every item has a number of 0 or 1) won't be very good (order `2^n`), but if most of the values of `Number` are of a similar order of magnitude to your target sum, as is the case in your example, then the stopping condition will fly in to your rescue and save you a large number of unnecessary operations.

Comment: A way to mitigate this might be to delete the row from the DataTable once you've used it. That way you are filtering and searching through an ever-decreasing pool of remaining rows.

Comment: My `SubsetsAddingUpTo` method basically does that.  Even so, the worst case is still `2^n`.

Comment: If there is an upper bound on the value of `Number`, then the stopping criterion can be expanded, because then you can hit a point in the chain where you know you've got no chance of hitting your target.

Comment: Am I acting stupid? In my test program I get following error: 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' does not contain a definition for 'Subsets' and no extension method 'Subsets' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to define `SubsetsAddingUpTo` in its own static class.  It's an extension method.  Make sure you have a reference to the namespace in which you've defined `SubsetsAddingUpTo`.